# SwiftUI generic navigation link using block variable

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

Here I would like to create navigation code, I'm able to do this `Swift` `UIKit`. I'm trying the same functionality in `SwiftUI`, but I'm facing an issue with my code. How can we convert the `SwiftUI` view to `AnyView`.

Is there any other way to achieve the same functionality in `SwiftUI`?

Your help would be greatly appreciated.!!

```swift
/// Swift code
public struct Navigator {
    public var onLoginSuccess: (UINavigationController) -> Void = { navigationController in
        navigationController.pushViewController(UIViewController(), animated: true)
    }
}

/// Usage
var router = Navigator()
router.onLoginSuccess = { nav in
    nav.pushViewController(UIViewController(), animated: true)
}


/// SwiftUI  Code
struct Navigator {
    static var onTap: (AnyView) -> Void = { view in
        _ = view.navigate(to: Text("SS"))
    }
}

extension View {
    func navigate<SomeView: View>(to view: SomeView) -> some View {
        modifier(NavigateModifier(destination: view))
    }
}


fileprivate struct NavigateModifier<SomeView: View>: ViewModifier {
    fileprivate let destination: SomeView
    
    fileprivate func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                content
                NavigationLink(destination: destination) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/// Usage 
NavigationView {
    Button("Home") {
        Navigator.onTap(self)
    }
}
```

Here is another solution code working fine with a single destination, but I can't change destination runtime. `Router.onLogin` should accept destination view.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            HStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: Router.onLogin) {
                    Text("HOME")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct Router {
    @ViewBuilder
    static var onLogin: some View {
        Text("Hello")
    }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work because your are returning a `Void` to a `Void`. Because of this `_ = ` . You have to somehow activate a `NavigationLink` in the `body` or a SwiftUI `ViewModifier`. Change something in the `action` of the `Button` to make a `NavigationLink` `active`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wouldn't work because in `Navigator` onTap return void and it will not push view on any view.

But you can do by this

```
extension View {
    /// Navigate to a new view.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - view: View to navigate to.
    ///   - binding: Active binding
    func navigate<NewView: View>(to view: NewView, when binding: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            self
            NavigationLink(
                destination: view,
                isActive: binding
            ) {
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isNextScreen: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Button("Home") {
                isNextScreen.toggle()
            }.navigate(to: Text("SS"),when: $isNextScreen)
        }
    }
}
```

#### Update

As you mention in a comment, you want multiple and dynamic destinations.

Then you can use it this way.

View extension for navigation

```
extension View {
    func navigate(to view: Binding<Navigator?>) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            self
            if let wrappedValue = view.wrappedValue {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: wrappedValue.navigateView,
                    tag: wrappedValue,
                    selection: view,
                    label: {EmptyView()})
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Create Navigator

```
enum Navigator: Identifiable {
    case onTap
    case onLogin
    
    var id: Navigator {
        return self
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var navigateView: some View {
        switch self {
        case .onTap:
            Text("SS")
            
        case .onLogin:
            Text("Login View")
        }
    }
}
```

Usage Content View

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var nextScreen: Navigator? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                Button("Home") {
                    nextScreen = .onTap
                }
                
                Button("Login") {
                    nextScreen = .onLogin
                }
                
            }.navigate(to: $nextScreen)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your support, is there any other way to same `Swift` functionality to get?  I mean here I'm not getting much benefit from our regular code. Because the action may decide where to navigate in run time. I can override the push `destination` when it's needed. I can do that from my swift code, but not in `SwiftUI` code.

Comment: @DRN so your requirement is: your destination view is many and decides the view at the time of button press right?

Comment: yes, it is working fine. thank you. Still, we have to maintain the `enum` right?. what if tomorrow we have `N` number of cases for `N` number of screens, we have to maintain enum. That's where I want to improve with the `polymorphism`. But It is really helpful to know another way.

Comment: Yes. You need to maintain ```enum```. But you have to write or add destination somewhere in code so it's better to add in enum.

Answer (score 0):

Here I got one *solution* to this issue, but not sure it's the best. I believe still we can improve this.

```swift
struct LoginView: View {
    
    var loginAction = Router().onLogin(AnyView(Text("Actual View Wll This")))
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: loginAction) {
                    Text("Show View")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: AnyView(Text("Detail"))) {
                    Text("Show Detail View")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension LoginView {
    struct Router {
        var onLogin:(AnyView) -> AnyView = { links in
            return AnyView(links)
        }
    }
}


/// Now I can change the 'Destination' for 'loginAction' in a scene and where ever I want.

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    var contentView = LoginView()
    contentView.loginAction =  AnyView(Text("Changed Route to here"))
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// After some improvements

```swift
struct LoginView: View {
    var loginAction = Router().onLogin(Text("Actual Detail View"))

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: loginAction) {
                    Text("Show View")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension LoginView {
    struct Router<Destination: View> {
        var onLogin:(Destination) -> Destination = { links in
            return links
        }
    }
}

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        
        var contentView = LoginView()
        contentView.loginAction =  LoginView.Router().onLogin(Text("Changed Route here .!!"))
        
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```